Experiencing the journey of a dead person
My maternal uncle died at the age of 82 in America recently. Since his son was not adapted as per hindu customs, the complete 13 day rituals was done by his younger brother in India. I was closer to the dead uncle and had a little troubled relationship with the uncle performing the final rites. I attended not wholeheartedly the 12th day that is bhoja.
On the 13th, my life had some sudden events. I was forced to extract a teeth and it resulted in excessive blood flow till 3 in the morning. Next three days I was forced to eat mashed up food. Even now I am having excessive thirst.
I later realised this is what death people experience in their journey - have to swallow things, experience heavy thirsts.
Why am I experiencing these? Is it bcoz he was dear to me? Is this some sort of punishment
